# Samsung S6 and S6 Edge WebView Issue

Tags: android, webview, samsung-mobile

I have an activity which handles any URL events within my application and it opens them within a web view. The issue which I currently have is that if i turn off the WiFi and turn it back on the URLs which were previously working before in the webview do not load and it eventually timeouts. The puzzling thing is that I have tried this within the same application across other phones (HTC, Samsung S5, LG Nexus 5, Samsung S4, One Plus One) and it works perfectly.

I am wondering if anyone has a solution for this or at least an explanation as to why this is happening.

The reason I'm asking this is on here is because although it seems to be a device specific issue, before to get another issue with my webview to work with samsungs i had to enable webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

I want to know if there would be something similar to help me with this S6 issue.

Comment: when I said It works perfectly I mean the same application with the same links on all other phones i've tried. I'm looking for a solution or at least an explanation as to why it doesn't work on samsung S6 or S6 edges

Comment: Not all phones use the same Android image, or codebase. Sometimes vendors break certain things, and fix them later down the road or don't fix them at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a device-specific issue. Not a programming issue.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I know It seems device specific however sometimes an extra method needs to be used sometimes. For example to get another issue with my webview to work with samsung i had to enable webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
I wanted to know if there would be something similar to help me with this S6 issue.

Comment: @David if we closed all Android issues caused by fragmentation, we may as well remove the Android tag altogether. Device fragmentation is a big & expensive part of Android development.

Comment: @JesterXiii Did you find a resolution for this issue? Thanks!

Comment: @KalaJ The reason for the problem is that samsung have their own personal webview variant on their phones so what I ended up doing was just kicking any samsung users out to the native browser instead of loading the webview.